# Knockout.js - basics of binding viewModel multiple times on asp.net mvc3 partial view

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using a knockout.js on my project to bind model to view. Basically, on document.ready function I use the code below:

```
 var viewModel = {
        firstName: ko.observable("John")
        listofChildren=ko.observablearray()
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    dataService.getChildren(viewModel); // This is no good need to move to partial view
```

i can use the above viewModel on most of pages. However, I've a requirement that for one partial view we call third party web service by Jquery and populate the listOfChildren property above.

Problem is that at the moment the call to webservice happens on document.ready which means every page refresh makes call to web service. I would like to make a call only if user loads the partial view.

I tried to move the call to third party webservice on partial view page but it shows viewModel is null.

```
dataService.getChildren(viewModel); //where dataService is a function which uses ajax call to webservice and populates the listofChildren array.
```

Could someone please help me how best above can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why moving the call to `getChildren` wasn't able to find `viewModel` after moving it to the partial view:

1. `viewModel` is scoped to the `document.ready` function, and isn't visible outside of there
2. The call to `getChildren` was happening before the `viewModel` was created

Here is what I would recommend:  Leave the `getChildren` call inside `document.ready`, but only execute it if the partial view exists by searching for something that only exists in the partial view.  If you find it, then load the children.

```
if ($('#SomethingInPartialView').length) {
    dataService.getChildren(viewModel);
}
```